# not able to get into else if statement in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am having one source file(CertExpiry.csv) in csv format below:

```
CertName,Expiry,AlertEmail,UserName,WhereUsed,Type,Additional Info
something.test1.com,11/21/2021,tom@xyz.com,Tom,Test-WEU-APPGW,Internal CA,
something.test2.com,7/15/2021,"harry@xyz.com,tom@xyz.com",Harry,Test-SEA-APPGW,Internal CA,
something.test3.com,7/16/2021,"tom@xyz.com,harry@xyz.com",Tom,Test-EUS-APPGW,External CA,
something.test4.com,not set,"tom@xyz.com,harry@xyz.com",Tom,Test-EUS-APPGW,External CA,
```

and I have written below script to print some data based on matching condition but unfortunately I am not able to enter into else condition and its not printing data as per my wish.

```
$data=import-csv .\CertExpiry.csv
$days = "-30"

foreach($i in $data) {

$CertName = $i.CertName
$Expiry = $i.Expiry
$AlertEmail = $i.AlertEmail
$UserName = $i.UserName
$WhereUsed = $i.WhereUsed
$Type = $i.Type

write-host "$CertName - $Expiry" -foregroundcolor magenta

if($Expiry -eq "not set"){ 
    write-host "Cert expiration date is not set for $CertName" -foregroundcolor Green 

    }

else {
    $Expiry = get-date $Expiry
    $Expiry1 = ($Expiry).adddays($days)

    if($Expiry1 -le $date){ 

    write-host "Cert $CertName will expire on $Expiry and alert email is $AlertEmail with $UserName and $WhereUsed and $Type" -foregroundcolor red
    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a random `$date` variable in your last `if` statement. Maybe you meant `$Expiry`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Abraham](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68452875/not-able-to-get-into-else-if-statement-in-powershell#comment120979292_68452875) already pointed out where the error was (`$date` was never defined). I also added some improvements, the *Limit Date* should be defined outside the loop:

```
$csv = @'
CertName,Expiry,AlertEmail,UserName,WhereUsed,Type,Additional Info
something.test1.com,11/21/2021,tom@xyz.com,Tom,Test-WEU-APPGW,Internal CA,
something.test2.com,7/15/2021,"harry@xyz.com,tom@xyz.com",Harry,Test-SEA-APPGW,Internal CA,
something.test3.com,7/16/2021,"tom@xyz.com,harry@xyz.com",Tom,Test-EUS-APPGW,External CA,
something.test4.com,not set,"tom@xyz.com,harry@xyz.com",Tom,Test-EUS-APPGW,External CA,
something.test5.com,6/16/2021,"tom@xyz.com,harry@xyz.com",Tom,Test-EUS-APPGW,External CA,
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$limitDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

foreach($i in $csv)
{
    $CertName = $i.CertName
    $Expiry = $i.Expiry -as [datetime]
    $AlertEmail = $i.AlertEmail
    $UserName = $i.UserName
    $WhereUsed = $i.WhereUsed
    $Type = $i.Type
    
    if(-not $Expiry)
    { 
        Write-host "Cert expiration date is not set for $CertName" -ForegroundColor Green 
        continue
    }

    if($Expiry -le $limitDate)
    { 
        Write-Host "Cert $CertName will expire on $Expiry and alert email is $AlertEmail with $UserName and $WhereUsed and $Type" -ForegroundColor Red
        continue
    }

    Write-Host "$CertName - $Expiry" -ForegroundColor Magenta
}
```

This results in:

```
something.test1.com - 11/21/2021 00:00:00
something.test2.com - 07/15/2021 00:00:00
something.test3.com - 07/16/2021 00:00:00
Cert expiration date is not set for something.test4.com
Cert something.test5.com will expire on 06/16/2021 00:00:00 and alert email is tom@xyz.com,harry@xyz.com with Tom and Test-EUS-APPGW and External CA
```